# Joint moments of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My approach to [this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27841/how-to-calculate-e-int-0tw-sdsn-n-geq-2) uses the following joint moments of
Brownian motion. For $n=1,2$ they are obvious and well-known, the others 
are not terribly hard to work out. Is there a reference where these 
formulas are given, or/and is there a  pattern to the coefficients?

Fix $t_1\leq t_2\leq t_3\leq\cdots \leq t_n$.
For odd values of $n$ we have $\mathbb{E}[W(t_1)\ W(t_2) \cdots W(t_n)]=0$
while for even values of $n$ we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}[W (t_1)\ W(t_2)]&=& t_1 \cr
\mathbb{E}[W (t_1)\ W(t_2)\ W(t_3)\ W(t_4)]&=& 2t_1 t_2+t_1t_3 \cr
\mathbb{E}[W (t_1)\ W(t_2)\ W(t_3)\ W(t_4)\ W(t_5)\ W(t_6)]&=& 2t_1t_2t_5+t_1  t_3  t_5 +4 t_1  t_2  t_4 +2 t_1  t_3  t_4 +6 t_1  t_2  t_3 
\end{eqnarray*}

I suppose everything about Brownian motion
has been worked out, but I can't find this in any of my books. 
It's not very important, but I'm just curious!

Comment: By the discussion before, we can suppose that $t_1<t_2<...<t_n.$  put $\xi_1=W_{t_1}, \xi_2=W_{t_2}-W_{t_1},...,\xi_n=W_{t_n}-W_{t_{n-1}}$, which are independent Gaussian variables. Then, we have $$E[W_{t_1}W_{t_2}...W_{t_n}]=E[\xi_1(\xi_1+\xi_2)...(\xi_1+\xi_2+...+\xi_n)],$$
Which could be done.  For the case three, it could be written as $$\xi_1(\xi_1+\xi_2)(\xi_1+\xi_2+\xi_3)=\sum_{i=1}^{3!}{\xi_1\xi_{[\frac{i}{3}]}}\xi_{i\%3}, \xi_0=\xi_3$$. I try to treat it as a growth of tree for each term like binary code in computer science ; but I don't get the explicit formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another formula for this joint moment can be found as Lemma 4.5 in a paper by J. Rosen and M.B. Marcus [Annals of Probability, vol. 20, no. 4 (1992) pp. 1603-1684]; the authors refer to it as "well-known".  The formula is this (for even $n$): The joint moment $E[W(t_1)W(t_2)\cdots W(t_n)]$ is the sum over all *pairings* $\{\{a(1),b(1)\},\{a(2),b(2)\},\ldots,\{a(n/2),b(n/2)\}\}$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n/2}E[W(t_{a(i)},t_{b(i)})].
$$
A pairing is simply a partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into $n/2$ doubletons.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I'd learned this many years ago but had forgotten it.

Answer (score 5):

By considering $t_1=t_2=...=t_{2n}$, the sum of the coefficients is the $2n$th moment of $W(1)$, $(2n-1)!!$, which is the number of paths of length $2n$ in Young's lattice from the empty partition to itself.

I haven't yet proven the following, but I think induction should work.

---

Conjecture:

The indices of the terms with positive coefficients correspond to Dyck words, so the number of terms in $E[W(t_1)W(t_2)...W(t_{2n})]$ is the $n$th Catalan number. $t_1 t_2 t_4$ corresponds to the Dyck word $++-+--$ with pluses in positions $(1, 2, 4)$.

The coefficient of the term corresponding to a Dyck word is the number of paths of length $2n$ in Young's lattice from the empty partition to itself such that the partition at each step has size equal to the height of the Dyck path. The coefficient of $t_{i_1}t_{i_2}...t_{i_n}$ is $\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-i_k)$. For example, the coefficient of $t_1 t_2 ... t_n$ equals $\prod_{k=1}^n (2k-k) = n!$ and paths in Young's lattice which ascend $n$ times and then descend $n$ times correspond to pairs of standard tableaux of the same shape, which are in bijection with permutations of $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

---

Comment: Thanks! This is a beautiful answer, but it will take me some time to digest it.

Comment: Your answer makes an unexpected and delightful connection between Brownian moments and combinatorics, but I've decided to accept John's answer. It is closer to what I was looking for, a reference and explanation in terms of probability. I'm sorry that I can't accept both answers!