# An identity for the Laplace transform of a random variable and Isserlis theorem

Tags: probability, random-variables, laplace-transform

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957351/proving-isserlis-theorem-for-n-4?answertab=active#tab-top) there is a clever proof of Isserlis' theorem, but it is based on a identity for the Laplace transform that I do not know how to prove.
Why is it that, given a random vector $X,$ it holds that $E(e^{s^\prime X})=e^{\frac{1}{2}s^\prime C s}$?
(Here, as in the above-mentioned post, $s^\prime$ is the transpose vector of $s$ and $C$ is the covariance Matrix of $X$)

Comment: The post referred to is about jointly Gaussian random variables. If you know that characteristic function of jointly Gaussian random variables you can get the Laplace transform using complex analysis.

Comment: yeap, you are right... for multivariate normal distributions the identity follows from the typical gaussian integral. It was a silly question, thanks :S